# How to revert mysql_native_password back to default security

Tags: mysql, node.js

First, I encountered an error in nodejs as I throw a data in my database `"MySQL Client does not support authentication protocol"`. Later I found the solution and I used this:

```mysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your new password';

flush privileges;
```

After that, I later found out that this has security concerns which is a risk of lower security protection. Now I want it to revert to normal.

How can I do that?